# How to create table sequentially on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So, I want to populate table sequentially like if I click on the table 3 button, this table generates first then if I click on table 1 then table one should be created and so on...
each table should be generated one by one.
If table 3 and table 1 are created first then there should not table 2 space in between them.
I tried using hidden and visible style visibility but it's not working as I'm expecting.

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
  
<div class="center">
  <button style="margin: 1%;">Table 1</button>
  <button style="margin: 1%">Table 2</button>
  <button style="margin: 1%">Table 3</button>
</div>
     
    
    <table id="table1">
      <h3> Table 1</h3>
      <!-- <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr> -->
      <tr>
        <td>Seq</td>
        <td>
          
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><input>
        </input></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
          <input>
          </input>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td><input>
        </input></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Name</td>
        <td><input>
        </input></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    
    </table>
    

    
    <table id="table2">
      <h3> Table 2</h3>
      <!-- <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr> -->
      <tr>
        <td>Seq</td>
        <td>
    
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><input>
          </input></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
          <input>
          </input>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td><input>
          </input></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Name</td>
        <td><input>
          </input></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    
    </table>
    <table id="table3">
      <h3> Table 3</h3>
      <!-- <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Country</th>
              </tr> -->
      <tr>
        <td>Seq</td>
        <td>
    
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><input>
          </input></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
          <input>
          </input>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td><input>
          </input></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Name</td>
        <td><input>
          </input></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    
    </table>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried and explain more specifically what went wrong.

Comment: hide all tables initially, have id's of table stored in a data attribute of button ex: `<button style="margin: 1%;" data-id="table1">Table 1</button>` and on click show that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) for this, which

> adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position

So you can hide all the tables initially with `display: none;` and then show them and append to the parrent node once the corresponding button is clicked:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

function show(n) {
  const table = document.getElementById(`table${n}`);
  table.style.display = 'block';
  container.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

#table1, #table2, #table3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <button style="margin: 1%" onclick="show(1)">Table 1</button>
  <button style="margin: 1%" onclick="show(2)">Table 2</button>
  <button style="margin: 1%" onclick="show(3)">Table 3</button>
</div>

<div id=container>
  <table id="table1">
    <th colspan="3">Table 1</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Seq</td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>
        <input>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table Name</td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  </table>



  <table id="table2">
    <th colspan="3">Table 2</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Seq</td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>
        <input>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table Name</td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <table id="table3">
    <th colspan="3">Table 3</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Seq</td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>
        <input>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table Name</td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to append, just change `display`

Comment: @ariel as I understand, OP wants to display the tables in the order the buttons are clicked.